# Button:active on ipad not working

Tags: css, ipad

I have a simple problem with buttons on an ipad.

I want the background-image to change when the user taps on the button, but the :active state does simply not work (it works on a desktop browser though, so the code/selector must be correct)

I've read that on single tap, :hover is applied, so i tried with that. but unfortunately, it remains in that state, until another button is pressed.

what can i do to change the image only for the time that the button is pressed?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69ydhqyj)

i've left

```
function skip() {}
```

empty, but everything else is like in my real app.

the active works in the desktop browser, but not on my ipad (just tested it to go sure, Ipad3, iOS 8.2, stock safari)

Comment: 1) Do other websites work correctly when pressing buttons? 2) Are you sure it's not a matter of too little difference in colour to be visible? Can you put the offending code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: i've updated the question with a fiddle <3

Comment: OK. I'm sorry to say I don't have an iPad here, but on my Android phone the fiddle behaves strangely: it works in portrait mode, but not in landscape mode. I wouldn't know what causes that, but maybe it'll give you a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: similar behavior for my android phone.. landscape: works, portrait: works.
ipad: neither does. wtf. this is not some strange exotic hack, is it?